# Thread-safe raising of F# events

Tags: multithreading, events, f#

I'm trying to do an F# async computation that calls an C# callback when ready. The code is the following:

```
type Worker() = 

    let locker = obj()
    let computedValue = ref None
    let started = ref false
    let completed = Event<_>()

    let doNothing() = ()

    member x.Compute(callBack:Action<_>) = 
        let workAlreadyStarted, action = 
            lock locker (fun () -> 
                match !computedValue with
                | Some value ->
                    true, (fun () -> callBack.Invoke value)
                | None ->
                    completed.Publish.Add callBack.Invoke
                    if !started then                            
                        true, doNothing
                    else
                        started := true
                        false, doNothing)
        action()
        if not workAlreadyStartedthen
            async {                

                // heavy computation to calc result
                let result = "result"

                lock locker (fun () -> 
                    computedValue := Some result
                    completed.Trigger result)
            } |> Async.Start
```

But there's a problem, I want to trigger the completed event outside the lock, but I want to make sure that the triggering is thread safe (Actually, in this small example I could just trigger the event outside the lock as I know no one else will subscribe to it, but that's not always the case).

In C# events this is very easy to accomplish:

```
    object locker = new object();
    event Action<string> MyEvent;

    void Raise()
    {
        Action<string> myEventCache;
        lock (locker)
        {
            myEventCache = MyEvent;
        }
        if (myEventCache != null)
        {
            myEventCache("result");
        }
    }
```

How can I do the equivalent with F# events, freezing the list of subscribers inside the lock but invoking it outside the lock?

Comment: Are you sure the C# freezes the subscriber list? Aren't you just taking a reference to the event?

Comment: Whenever you add a new handler to an event, you create a new delegate value and replace the previous value, so as I'm copying the value of the delegate, if another handler is added after that, it won't be linked to the copy that was made

Comment: If you need access to the subscriber list, then you can use your own `IEvent<_>` implementation instead of the one provided by `Event<_>.Publish`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as straightforward in F# because `Event<_>` doesn't expose its subscriber list, which is mutated by `Add`/`Remove`.

You can avoid this mutation by creating a new event for each handler.

```
let mutable completed = Event<_>()

//...

let ev = Event<_>()
let iev = ev.Publish
iev.Add(completed.Trigger)
iev.Add(callBack.Invoke)
completed <- ev

//...

let ev = lock locker <| fun () -> 
    computedValue := Some result
    completed
ev.Trigger(result)
```